# Change JTable's entire row colour while adding rows from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have a JPanel like below

[image]

The data in the Transaction table (RIGHT) is generated from a MySQL resultset when the user selects a row in the Plot Table (LEFT). Code below:

```
        tableModelTran.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
        if (rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                java.util.Vector data = new java.util.Vector();
                data.add(rs.getString(1));
                data.add(rs.getString(2));
                data.add(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(rs.getDate(3)));
                data.add(String.valueOf(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy").format(rs.getDate(3))).toUpperCase());
                data.add(rs.getString(4));
                data.add(rs.getString(5));
                data.add(rs.getString(6));
                data.add(rs.getBoolean(7));
                tableModelTran.addRow(data);
            }

            performTotals();
        }
```

I would like to change the colour of the rows to GREEN if the 'Verified' column is ticked and leave uncoloured if it is not. Also, if the user changes the value of the column, the colour should update accordingly. Any and all help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I created a class and added it to my constructor as below:

```
static class ColorRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        java.awt.Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (value.equals(true)) {
            c.setBackground(java.awt.Color.GREEN);
        }

        return c;
    } 


public PlotDetailsWindow() {
    initComponents();
    ....
    ....
    transactionTable.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new ColorRenderer());
    ....
    ....
}
```

Now whenever I click select a row from the table on the left, if the first value is false, it will not change the colour but if it is true it will change just the 'Verified' column to green and then it doesn't matter if the value is true or false it will always be green. Also, the check boxes turned to true/false now.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to change the colour of the rows to GREEN if the 'Verified' column is ticked

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).

It shows how to override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of `JTable` to color an entire row based on the data in the row.

The basic structure for overriding this method would be as follows:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(
        TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        //  add custom rendering here

        return c;
    }
};
```

Comment: and how do I add this piece of code to my table in netbeans?

Comment: @HMH, I have never used an IDE so I can't tell you how to do this. You have been given working examples that shows you how to do this without an IDE. Learn how to code a Swing GUI without using an IDE. The code will be more portable if you ever need to move to a different IDE. This way you spend time learn Java instead of learning an IDE. The IDE can then only be used to structure the project code and debug the code.

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't help me much in getting my problem solved. Thank you for your contribution though.

Comment: @HMH, `that didn't help me much` - I gave you working code if you download the example from the link. How does that not help? You question was about how to color rows in a table and you were given the answer so the question should be "accepted" so people know the problem has been solved. If you don't know how to extend a class when you use the NetBeans IDE then you need to ask a question about the Netbeans IDE!